# checking a checkbox having random ids in cucumber-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, automation, cucumber, automated-tests

i have a scenario where i want to check/verify that the checkbox is disabled/checked.i have all the required steps which uses id of the element to verify/check the checkbox.Now i have a checkbox whose id is randomly generated after submit as shown below

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="event_ticket_attributes_new_1363260967734" name="event[ticket_attributes][new_1363260967734]" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

and after running again ,the same scenario

```
<input disabled="disabled" id="event_ticket_attributes_new_1363261186173" name="event[ticket_attributes][new_1363261186173]" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

**How can I have a step to check/verify such kind of checkboxes??**

Comment: Are there multiple checkboxes like that on the page? I.e (do more than one start with `event-ticket`)

Comment: Go through [this](http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-use-functions-in-xpath-in.html) post. Depending on your requirement, you can use one of the solutions provided in this link.